# guardar datos en una base de datos desde html y php

Tags: php, html, jquery, phpmyadmin, webservice

Intento guardar los datos sacados desde un formulario pero al insertar datos desde el navegador no me arroja error alguno pero al revisar la base de datos no contiene nada.

El formulario es este:

```
    <!REGISTRO DE NUEVO USUARIO>
            <div class="registro_usuario">
                <form class ="registro_usuario"action="conexion.php" method="POST" name="registro_usuario">
               <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro de usuario</p>
               <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuario/Email" required>
               <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="password" id="comprobar_password" name="comprobar_password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="submit" id="registro_final" name="registro_final" value="Registro" >
               </form>
            </div > <!REGISTRO DE NUEVO USUARIO>
```

y mi archivo php con la conexión a la base de datos junto a comandos sql, que es este:

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'asd';


    //Generar conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysql_error());

    insertar($conexion);

    function insertar($conexion){
        $nombre  =$_POST['nombre'];
        $password =$_POST['password'];
        $email =$_POST['email'];
       
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (Nombre,Clave,Email) VALUES ('$nombre','$password','$email')";

        mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Utiliza echo mysqli_error($conexion); despues de mysqli_query, esta función muestra los errores en la consulta, despues comentas que te salio

Comment: umh no me arrojo nada, pero al revisar las herramientas de desarrollador en el navegador me dice Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Answer (score 0):

en tu codigo hay algunos problemas de vulnerabiliad al momento de ingresar la informacion. Aqui hay una guia rapida sobre [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Ahora para ingresar la informacion, lo mejor seria lo siguiente.

```php
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'asd';


    //Generar conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysql_error());


    function insertar($data){
        global $conexion;
        $nombre  =$data['nombre'];
        $password =$data['password'];
        $email =$data['email'];
       
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (Nombre,Clave,Email) VALUES ('$nombre','$password','$email')";

        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        if($conexion->affected_rows > 0){
           return true;
        }else{
           return $conexion->error;
        }
    }

    insertar($_POST);
?>
```